# ios - format the information shared with share sheet

Tags: ios, swift, ios-sharesheet

I am using the following code to present a share sheet:

```
let url = "https://somelink.com"
let image = "https://myserver/an_image.png"
let text = "Join now!"
    
let shareSheetVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image, url, text], applicationActivities: nil)
    
shareSheetVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
shareSheetVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
present(shareSheetVC, animated: true)
```

What I'd like is something like this:

[image]

However, when I share I just get

https://somelink.com
https://myserver/an_image.png
Join now!

How can I format this to accomplish something like the example?

Comment: Have you tried to download the image first then attach the image as a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic example to share `Text`, `Image` and `URL` using `UIActivityViewController`

```
 let text = "Join Now!"
 let image =  UIImage(named: "your_image")
 let myWebsite = URL(string: "https://somelink.com")
 let shareAll = [text , image! , myWebsite]
 let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
 activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 
 activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame

 self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could approach this from a different angle and try to fix your webpage by adding:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://myserver/an_image.png">
<title>Join now!</title>
```

Those tags will be picked up by default from the *UIActivityViewController*.